# Xcode 4.3 set attributes for a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.3

Can hide or show a button in xcode from other viewController, the scenario is like this I am using navigation controller i already made hidden buttons, what i want to make the hidden buttons visible when press on a button from other viewController.

Comment: hide buttons in navigation controller bar

Comment: This sounds like a bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push your buttons onto the other Viewcontroller. Just add there `ButtonName.Hidden=NO`.